# Takes too long to establish that a linked server has no connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Our clients can have up to 200 linked SQL Servers to a central Head Office SQL Server. On our routine polling of all linked servers we sometimes come across ones that have been turned off. It takes up to 30 seconds for our procedures to understand this and move to the next server in our list. The working connections return results very quickly; I can can say, with confidence, that if we don't get our results back within 2 seconds then there is a problem with the connection.
I have been unable to find a way to change timeouts.
Is there a way for an attempt to get data from a linked server to abort with failure if it doesn't complete within 2 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a linked server object you can specify the "connection timeout" have you tried to change that?

If this is set to 0 it will use the general "remote query timeout" on server level. You can also look at the "query timeout" aswell.

[Linked Server Properties (Server Options Page)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: I have tried that and it reduces the time to terminate a connection attempt greatly. Thanks.